# D3 collapsable force cannot update data --> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'node' of null

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, metro-ui-css

its my json

```
var data =
[{
    name:"Words",
    children:[{
        name:"Nouns",
        children:[
            {
            name:"Table",
            size:1025
            },
            {
            name:"Box",
            size:2925
            },
            {
            name:"Bat",
            size:4025
            },
                ],
        size: 2000
    },
    {
        name:"Adverbs",
        children:[
            {
            name:"eagerly",
            size:2520
            },
            {
            name:"badly",
            size:3259
            },
            {
            name:"easily",
            size:2512
            },
                ],
        size: 425
    },
    {
        name:"Adjectives",
        children:[
            {
            name:"Positive",
            children:[
            {
            name:"Amazing",
            size:1250
            },
            {
            name:"Beautiful",
            size:2529
            }],
            size:1000
            },

            {
            name:"Negative",
            children:[
            {
            name:"Destructive",
            size:1250
            },
            {
            name:"Hot",
            size:2529
            }],
            size:1000
            },
                ],
        size: 343
    },

    {
        name:"Verbs",
        children:[
            {
            name:"Play",
            size:4310
            },
            {
            name:"Say",
            size:2943
            },
            {
            name:"Ride",
            size:4430
            },
                ],
        size: 343
    },
          ],
    size: 2000
}];
```

initialized with null

```
var g = {
    data: null,
    force: null
 };
```

created graph

```
 $(function () {

 //use a global var for the data:
  g.data = data;


var width = 1300,
    height = 630;


//Create a sized SVG surface within viz:
var svg = d3.select("#viz")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);


g.link = svg.selectAll(".link"),
g.node = svg.selectAll(".node");

//Create a graph layout engine:
g.force = d3.layout.force()
    .linkDistance(150)
    .charge(-300)
    .gravity(0.01)
    .size([width, height])
//that invokes the tick method to draw the elements in their new location:
.on("tick", tick);



//Draw the graph:
//Note that this method is invoked again
//when clicking nodes:
update();


});

    function update() {

    //iterate through original nested data, and get one dimension array of nodes.
    var nodes = flatten(g.data);

    //Each node extracted above has a children attribute.
    //from them, we can use a tree() layout function in order
    //to build a links selection.
    var links = d3.layout.tree().links(nodes);

    // pass both of those sets to the graph layout engine, and restart it
```

## **Here is where error occur**

```
               g.force.nodes(nodes)  //Here is where error occur
                 .links(links)
                 .start();
 ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////    

    //-------------------
    // create a subselection, wiring up data, using a function to define 
    //how it's suppossed to know what is appended/updated/exited
    g.link = g.link.data(links, function (d) {return d.target.id;});

    //Get rid of old links:
    g.link.exit().remove();

    //Build new links by adding new svg lines:
    g.link
        .enter()
        .insert("line", ".node")
        .attr("class", "link");

    // create a subselection, wiring up data, using a function to define 
    //how it's suppossed to know what is appended/updated/exited
    g.node = g.node.data(nodes, function (d) {return d.id;});
    //Get rid of old nodes:  
    g.node.exit().remove();
    //-------------------
    //create new nodes by making groupd elements, that contain circls and text:
    var nodeEnter = g.node.enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .on("click", click)
        .call(g.force.drag);
    //circle within the single node group:
    nodeEnter.append("circle")
        .attr("r", function (d) {return Math.sqrt(d.size) || 50;});
    //text within the single node group:
    nodeEnter.append("text")
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .text(function (d) {
        return d.name;
    });
    //All nodes, do the following:
    g.node.select("circle")
        .style("fill", color); //calls delegate
    //-------------------
}


// Invoked from 'update'.
// The original source data is not the usual nodes + edge list,
 // but that's what's needed for the force layout engine. 
// So returns a list of all nodes under the root.
function flatten(data) {
    var nodes = [],
        i = 0;
    //count only children (not _children)
    //note that it doesn't count any descendents of collapsed _children 
    //rather elegant?
    function recurse(node) {
        if (node.children) node.children.forEach(recurse);
        if (!node.id) node.id = ++i;
        nodes.push(node);
    }
    recurse(data);

    //Done:
    return nodes;
}


update();


//Invoked from 'update'
//Return the color of the node
//based on the children value of the 
//source data item: {name=..., children: {...}}
function color(d) {
    return d._children ? "#3182bd" // collapsed package
    :
    d.children ? "#c6dbef" // expanded package
    :
        "#fd8d3c"; // leaf node
}






// Toggle children on click by switching around values on _children and children.
function click(d) {
    if (d3.event.defaultPrevented) return; // ignore drag
    if (d.children) {
        d._children = d.children;
        d.children = null;
    } else {
        d.children = d._children;
        d._children = null;
    }
    //
    update();
}



//event handler for every time the force layout engine
//says to redraw everthing:
function tick() {
    width=1300;
    height=630;
    r=60;
     g.node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x = Math.max(r, Math.min(width - r, d.x)); })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y = Math.max(r, Math.min(height - r, d.y)); });
    //redraw position of every link within the link set:

    g.link.attr("x1", function (d) {
        return d.source.x;
    })
        .attr("y1", function (d) {
        return d.source.y;
    })
        .attr("x2", function (d) {
        return d.target.x;
    })
        .attr("y2", function (d) {
        return d.target.y;
    });
    //same for the nodes, using a functor:
    g.node.attr("transform", function (d) {
        return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    });



    }
```

**Whenever i add my new json with the same format it doesnt show anything. and the error tracebacks to the code the == update(); ==

jquery version: 2.1.3

d3 version : 3.4.13

dont know if it matters or not but i am intergrating this in http://metroui.org.ua/
Metro Ui tabs
Please help!**

Comment: Which line is causing the error?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff i highlighted the part where the error occur

Comment: Sounds like the code that initialises the force layout etc isn't executed.

Comment: in html first loaded Jquery then d3 then this script. which is intializing the force layout on page load. that i presume is the way  ?

Comment: Yes. Could you provide a complete example that reproduces the error please, ideally on jsfiddle or something like that?